# HTML style email in php

Tags: php, html, email

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array($dataz);

$body = '
<html>
<head>
  <title> Summary Report </title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Type of incident: {$info['type']}</p>
  <p>Date upon entry: {$info['date']}</p>   
  <p>Time upon entry: {$info['time']}</p>
  <p>Your account name: {$info['reporter']}</p>
  <p>Your incident ID number: {$info['ID']}</p>
  <p>Your description of the incident: {$info['desc']}</p>  
</body>
</html>';

$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


mail($info['email'], "subject!", $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initialising your `$body` string with single quotes when you need to use double quotes to take advantage of PHP's variable replacement.

Comment: gahh that's annoying, I had used double quotes originally, but in an effort to debug, I changed them to single quotes

Answer (score 2):

You can't use variables in single-quotes.

```
php > $hallo = 'Bla';
php > $hello = 'Bla';
php > echo '{$hello} there.';
{$hello} there.
php > echo "{$hello} there.";
Bla there.
```

Use double quotes (") in your $body instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should be added in to your email in the following way:

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array($dataz);

$body = '
<html>
<head>
  <title> Summary Report </title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Type of incident: ' . $info['type'] . '</p>
  <p>Date upon entry: ' . $info['date'] . '</p>   
  <p>Time upon entry: ' . $info['time'] . '</p>
  <p>Your account name: ' . $info['reporter'] . '</p>
  <p>Your incident ID number: ' . $info['ID'] . '</p>
  <p>Your description of the incident: ' . $info['desc'] . '</p>  
</body>
</html>';

$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


mail($info['email'], "subject!", $body, $headers);
```

Presumably that's one of your problems gone

Is the message actually sending?
Is it that it's not showing in the HTML format, as expected?